# Prolog creating a list of sets from ith elements of lists

Tags: prolog

I have list structure

```
L=[[a,b,c,d],[a,f,c,h]]
```

Length of L can be greater than 2.I want to unite the elements of list so that L or a NewL become

```
L=[a,[b,f],c,[d-h]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "uniting"? You state `a` presumably, because the elements are the same, but don't you rather mean `[a]`? How should this work out for `L = [[[a]],[[a]]]`?

Comment: Are you trying to implement some sort of "motif" finding, or structure alignment? If so, it is worth implementing an existing algorithm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're requiring is an aggregation schema. I think I got it:

```
unite(Ls, [E|Es]) :-
    aggreg(Ls, E, Ns),
    unite(Ns, Es).
unite(_, []).

aggreg(L, E, LLs) :-
    maplist(first, L, Fs, LLs),
    setof(X, member(X, Fs), S),
    ( [E] = S -> true ; E = S ).

first([E|Es], E, Es).
```

yields

```
?- L=[[a,b,c,d],[a,f,c,h],[a,f,c,g]],unite(L,U).
L = [[a, b, c, d], [a, f, c, h], [a, f, c, g]],
U = [a, [b, f], c, [d, g, h]] ;
L = [[a, b, c, d], [a, f, c, h], [a, f, c, g]],
U = [a, [b, f], c] .
```

I think that a cut after the first solution would be well placed (use [once](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=once/1)/1 for that).

Note that the schema it's rather general: just substitute in setof/3 some more applicative task (if any) than unification (you could call into your DB, for instance).

Comment: sometime it's really hard to imagine the reason of downvotes. I could understand if there was a better answer, or if it would be wrong, or the question were presumably homework. But here ? What's problem here ? Any hint is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
unite([[],[]], []).
unite([[X|Ls], [X|Rs]], [X|Rest]) :- unite([Ls, Rs], Rest).
unite([[L|Ls], [R|Rs]], [[L,R]|Rest]) :- L \= R, unite([Ls, Rs], Rest).
```

However, I agree with @false because this is a strange API and there are a lot of unhandled edge cases.